# How to use tar with an argument in the path

Tags: bash, tar

I am trying to tar some files into a destination, where FILES path and DESTINATION were entered as arguments ($1 and $2): script FILE DEST

I want to tar the files into the destination and change the name (ex: add the word "update" and the date at the end of the filename) at the end of the new tar file

So I have: date=date dest=$2 files="$1/*" #considers all the files within the directory given, as files is a . directory containing one or more files tar $dest/"update"$date $files

however, this does not work, and I get the error: tar: Old option 'u' requires an argument (as in the u in "update" I assume)

Comment: Take a look at the documentation of tar: `man tar`

Comment: First echo the command that the script would launch

Comment: I have changed it to tar [/$dest/'backup$date'] [$files] and still get the same error message

Comment: @prince12 Did you actually use square brackets in the command, and single-quotes around a variable reference? Neither of these things is ok. Please edit your question to show exactly what you've tried, using [code format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), and use the preview to make sure it renders correctly. There's no point at all in asking what's wrong with the code in your question when it has *different* problems from what your actual code has.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little unclear from your description, but it appears you are trying to make a script that will take a directory name you call `FILE` as the first argument and then a name for your archive as the second argument you call `DEST` to which you want to append `"_update_$(date +%F).tar.xz"` (or choose the compression type you wish). You then want to create a TAR archive similar to:

```
tar -cJf "${2}_update_$(date +%F).tar.xz" "$1"/*
```

A script to do that is relatively straight forward, and we will add the `-J` option to use `xz` compression for the archive. Your `FILE` and `DEST` names are confusing, so let's use `dname` for the directory containing the files and `tarname` for the archive name. The after appending `"_update_$(date +%F).tar.xz"` to your `tarname` input you could do:

```
#!/bin/bash

[ -z "$1" ] || [ -z "$2" ] && { ## validate 2 arguments given
    printf "error: insufficient input\nusage: %s file dest\n" "${0##*/}" >&2
    exit 1
}

dirname="$1"                              ## name of directory to archive
tarname="${2}_update_$(date +%F).tar.xz"  ## archive name

tar -cJf "$tarname" "$dirname"/*          ## create compressed archive
```

**Example Directory to Archive**

```
$ ls -al tmpd/
total 4
drwxr-xr-x  2 david david 180 Sep 26 11:15 .
drwxrwxrwt 20 root  root  420 Sep 26 11:16 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 david david   0 Sep 26 11:15 a
-rw-r--r--  1 david david   0 Sep 26 11:15 b
-rw-r--r--  1 david david   0 Sep 26 11:15 c
-rw-r--r--  1 david david   0 Sep 26 11:15 d
-rw-r--r--  1 david david   0 Sep 26 11:15 e
-rw-r--r--  1 david david   0 Sep 26 11:15 f
-rw-r--r--  1 david david 111 Sep 22 22:08 file
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash quicktar.sh tmpd myfiles
```

The archive is created:

```
$ ls -al myfiles_update_2019-09-26.tar.xz
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 460 Sep 26 11:16 myfiles_update_2019-09-26.tar.xz
```

Finally check the content of the compressed archive:

```
$ tar -tJf myfiles_update_2019-09-26.tar.xz
tmpd/a
tmpd/b
tmpd/c
tmpd/d
tmpd/e
tmpd/f
tmpd/file
```

Look things over and let me know if that is what you intended. You can drop compression or change the type just by changing the `-J` option in the command above.

Comment: thank you! what does the -f switch do? I am still getting en error: tar: Removing leading `/' from member names

Comment: @prince12 `f` specifies a tar file (as opposed to using `stdio`). The string following `f` is the `tar` file name. It's described in the `tar` manual page. You really should read that if you want to use `tar`.  The message you're describing is information, not an error. `tar` stores relative paths, not absolute starting with `/`. So `/home/foo/...` will be stored in the `tar` archive as `home/foo/...`.

Comment: @prince12 yes, sorry for the delay, real-world called. While Linux man pages (e.g. `man tar`) may look cryptic at first, if you want to know exactly how a command works, the man page lists every option and a description. The cryptic look fades quickly and you will so come to rely on them daily. Let me know if you have further questions.